# The tensor product of the canonical line bundle and k(x) for a closed point x

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties, line-bundles

I am reading the book “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry” by Daniel Huybrechts. At the beginning of the page 91, it is written that if $X$ is a smooth projective variety with a canonical bundle $\omega_X$, then for a closed point $x\in X$, we have $k(x)\cong k(x)\otimes \omega_X$. My question is that why is this true?

Comment: Line bundles are by definition locally free sheaves of rank one. It doesn’t mean they’re globally free at all, and the Picard group is the group that detects that defect.

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, I guess you are right. I will edit my question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you at least know the definition of the tensor product of sheaves? Or any results about how to compute this?

Comment: @KReiser I know the definition of tensor products of sheaves. As I looked for it here, some other people also asked this and some people answered them that we can check it locally. But it works when we have a morphism, we can not always say that two sheaves are isomorphic iff they are isomorphic locally, but it is true for morphisms of sheaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}\cong \widetilde{F}$, $\mathcal{G}\cong \widetilde{G}$ for $A$-modules $F,G$, the tensor product $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$ is exactly the sheaf $\widetilde{F\otimes G}$. This implies that for any scheme $X$, quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ and affine open $U\subset X$, we have $\mathcal{F}(U)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X(U)}\mathcal{G}(U)\cong (\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G})(U)$. We'll use this result to compute in your case.

Now suppose $U\subset X$ is an affine open subscheme where $\omega_X$ is free. If $x\notin U$, then $k(x)(U)=0$ and so $k(x)\otimes\omega_X$ is a skyscraper sheaf supported at $x$. If $x\in U$, then we're looking at the tensor product $k(x)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X(U)} \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, which is exactly $k(x)$, so the stalk at $x$ is exactly $k(x)$ and in fact the tensor product $k(x)\otimes\omega_X\cong k(x)$.